# Помощь в создании скрипта автоматической конфигурации Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, config

Поскольку настройка, например 10 компов, на данный момент занимает от 6ти часов и выше(в зависимости от качества удалённого соединения) и даже последовательное прокликивание настроек на одновременно 4х машинах дело не ускоряет, было принято решение сваять скриптик во благо тайм-менеджмента

С большего это всего лишь автоматизация дебильных копаний в настройках системы, фаервола, таск менеджера и прочих базовых потребностей.

В идеале от меня хотят видеть *"одну волшебную кнопку которая сама сделает всё за пару минут"*

Начал я исесно с гугления и поиска скриптов по каждому пункту

Что должно быть включено в основной скрипт:

**Создать пользователя с фиксированным именем и паролем**

**task scheduler  3am reboot (shutdown /r /f /t 0)**

**Установка нашего фирменного "Агента" и добавление всех его компонентов в shell:startup и windows defender firewall**

**отключение обновлений с помощью wu10man  или каким-нибудь другим способом (wu10man во всяком случае делал именно то, что там надо)**

**Настройка параметров windows:**

security at a glance - всё должно быть отключено  (no actions needed)

**отключение bluetooth**

**отключение уведомлений 
отключение впадения компьютера в спячку
 отключение cortana и мусора в Task Manager (Disable "microsoft OneDrive’) 
(Для всего этого я нашел Sophia Script. Думаю, что можно "повыдирать" только необходимое)**

**Установка сплошного цвета**

**Autologon**

"users must enter a user name ... " must be disabled

Установка дополнительного ПО (Remotix Agent, Log me in)

Краткая суть вопроса такова:
Объеденить несколько скриптов в один
Поскольку я ничерта не понимаю в программировании, синтаксис для меня это тёмный лес, а задачу надо выполнить в достаточно сжатые сроки (дедлайн уже в пятницу), времени на детальное изучение вопроса просто нет
Единственное, что в моих силах это копипастить команды по очереди(надеясь, что я нашёл именно то, что мне надо и оно будет работать). Однако такой подход никого не устраивает.
Жирным выделил то, что удалось таки найти
Остальное под вопросом

Очень прошу - помогите хоть советом, хоть ссылкой решить данную проблему.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/6cpcui
Что должно быть включено в основной скрипт - со ссылками

Comment: Можете пойти на фриланс и найти так компетентного человека для такой задачи.

Comment: Жизнь порой несправедливая штука
Никто не хочет выделить на это бюджет, наших программистов никто не хочет занимать этим, а я со своей запралтой едва концы с концами свожу

Comment: Ты щас описал те задачи, которые я уже 3+ года делаю с помощью `ansible` (ага, именно на винде). Рекомендую копать в эту сторону.

Comment: А... дедлайн. Ну "прям щас" - тут или залить деньгами или ночевать (не забудь взять еды и кофе). А потом садись за ansible\gpo.